The token was hacked in my smart contract
The transactions below were not created by me.
Someone else withdrew tokens from my smart contract.
The hack occurred in a transaction that creates a smart contract.
How is this possible?
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x9464ad3a3216109fa056ae7d3e62cc7306175464f293452fa1378bfd2ee8c313
My Smart Contract: 0x0097fa829ca7f4771215c8d397ab3821e49e9a24

If a token was transferFrom you then you signed a bad approval. If transfer from you they have your private key. If you copy pasted code and sent it money, then it's just a scam.
